# How can I make Knockout.Mapping working in ASP.NET Web App?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm constructing a MVC5 Web App and want to make a dynamic page view by using Knockout.js. However, I have found that Knockout.Mapping doesn't seem to work correctly in my project.

As you see Intellisense does not the suggestion for the mapping plugin (I have included the reference of the plugin in the _reference.js). And it fails to show the second alert written when I complete this line forcibly.

Do I have to do something more to make it work correctly?

```
@if (false)
{
<script src = "~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js" ></script >
<script src = "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script >
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js")"></script>

//~~body~~//

<script type="text/javascript">
alert("1");
var json = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
b = ko.mapping.fromJson(json); //"mapping" is not suggested when "ko." is put.
//b = ko.mapping.fromJson(Model); //mistake at the original post
ko.applyBindings(b);
alert("2"); // not showed when the previous two lines is active.
</script>
```

[image: Intellisense is not working]

Comment: Didn't you try to set the model in the beginning of the page with @model, did you?

Comment: Yes, I put "@model..." referring the viewmodel in the beginning of the cshtml.

Comment: I have found that I made a mistake in the code and did not upload a screenshot. I have modified the post, leaving the original lines. Sorry for making it confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delaying follow-up. Finally I make it working by using

```
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>    

//~~body~~//

@section scripts{
        <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
}
```

and show the suggest by putting

```
/// <reference path="knockout.mapping-latest.js" />
```

after the reference of the core library of knockout.js in _reference.js.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the help available [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Using-KO-with-ASP.NET-MVC).

I think the example you will need to create your mapping is this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)))
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I checked that Newtonsoft package was installed correctly. Thank you for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var ViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;

   self.formData2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
 }
```

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(new ExecutivoViewModel());
    }
```

My ViewModel Class:

```
 public class ExecutivoViewModel
{
    public ExecutivoViewModel() { }

    public ExecutivoViewModel(Executivo entidade)
    {
        this.ExecutivoId = entidade.ExecutivoId;
        this.Nome = entidade.Nome;
        this.Cargo = entidade.Cargo;
        this.Inativo = entidade.Inativo;
    }

    [DisplayName("Executivo ID")]
    [Required]
    public int ExecutivoId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cargo")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Cargo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Inativo")]
    public bool Inativo { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will soon try the approach you have suggested and update the result.